# Google Cloud Platform - Scheduler?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, cron, google-cloud-platform, scheduler

I have a real time `Node` application which I plan to run on Google Cloud.  It is real time because the sever must always be in sync with `Firebase`.  For example, to process Search functionality etc. So I will have this constantly ticking thing, which just sits waiting for Events to happen.

One of the core parts of the application is the concept that `Events` (Date and Time) can be created.

What I need, is essentially a Black Box.  I want to say "Tell me at 23rd of December at 8pm about this Event". Kind of like a Mega long callback or something I can subscribe to.

I know that `cron` is available, but that isn't quite what I want. A cron has no real business in an real time application and doesn't feel right.  My Application should adapt to Events. I don't want a machine gun firing once a minute 24/7 especially when no changes have been made to the system. I need to ditch the time based polling idea.

I believe what I really need is a `Scheduler` which appears to be like a Cron, but more "Real time".

This led me [Microsoft Azure which has a Scheduler](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/scheduler/)

I think that might be exactly what I need. If so, is there a Google Cloud equivalent that I may be missing in the Docs?

Answer (score 4):

The GAE flexible environment offers a similar cron service.

From [Scheduling Jobs with cron.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml):

> The App Engine Cron Service allows you to configure regularly
>   scheduled tasks that operate at defined times or regular intervals.
>   These tasks are commonly known as *cron jobs*. These cron jobs are
>   automatically triggered by the App Engine Cron Service. For instance,
>   you might use this to send out a report email on a daily basis, to
>   update some cached data every 10 minutes, or to update some summary
>   information once an hour.
>
> A cron job will invoke a URL, using an HTTP GET request, at a given
>   time of day. An HTTP request invoked by cron can run for up to 60
>   minutes, but is [subject to the same limits as other HTTP
>   requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/how-requests-are-handled#quotas_and_limits).

From [About cron.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml#about)

> The following is an example cron.yaml file:
>
> ```
> cron:
> - description: daily summary job
>   url: /tasks/summary
>   schedule: every 24 hours
> - description: monday morning mailout
>   url: /mail/weekly
>   schedule: every monday 09:00
>   timezone: Australia/NSW
> - description: new daily summary job
>   url: /tasks/summary
>   schedule: every 24 hours
>   target: beta
> ```

So all you need to do is to configure such cron jobs (triggers) for whatever actions you need and add handlers for the respective URLs performing those actions.

From [The schedule format](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml#the_schedule_format):

> The following are examples of schedules:
>
> ```
> every 12 hours
> every 5 minutes from 10:00 to 14:00
> every day 00:00
> every monday 09:00
> 2nd,third mon,wed,thu of march 17:00
> 1st monday of sep,oct,nov 17:00
> 1 of jan,april,july,oct 00:00
> ```

Note: it's not yet possible to schedule the cron jobs programmatically, but there's a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35887847) for it.

The **cron.yaml** for the particular example mentioned in the question:

```
cron:
- description: trigger the Dec 23rd event
  url: /events/12.23
  schedule: 23 of dec 20:00
```

To deploy the cron job:

```
gcloud app deploy cron.yaml
```

Comment: this is just a copy/paste from google cloud platform... can you provide an actual example with detailed steps on how to deploy the cron job!?

Comment: @Learn2Code Done. Do you think it answers the question better?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, Google Cloud Functions - and more generally Functions As A Service / Serverless - seem like the best fit for running event driven pieces of code. 
On GCP, it basically consists into uploading to a bucket a nodejs module, with your logic embedded into an exported function.

From the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart) :

```
/**
 * Cloud Function.
 *
 * @param {object} event The Cloud Functions event.
 * @param {function} callback The callback function.
 */
exports.helloWorld = function helloWorld (event, callback) {
  console.log(`My Cloud Function: ${event.data.message}`);
  callback();
};
```

You can read more about [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/).